# Python pandas: adding list of elements in a specific column to find all_elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a column using pandas.dataframe like so:

```
id  available_fruits  
1   ['apple', 'banana']   
1   []
2   ['apple', 'tomato']
1   ['banana']
2   ['kiwi']
```

I want to create `all_available_fruits` list without duplicates, which should be `['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi', 'tomato']`.

In other word, I want to add all elements in list, in pandas.dataframe column. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) for flatennig and then [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
a = np.unique(np.concatenate(df['available_fruits'].values.tolist())).tolist()
print(a)

['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi', 'tomato']
```

Another solution is flatten by `chain.from_iterable`, get unique by `set` and last convert to `list` :

```
from  itertools import chain
a = list(set(chain.from_iterable(df.available_fruits.values.tolist())))
print(a)
['tomato', 'kiwi', 'apple', 'banana']
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)
#print (df)

In [62]: %timeit list(set(concat(df.available_fruits.values.tolist())))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.16 ms per loop

In [63]: %timeit np.unique(np.concatenate(df['available_fruits'].values.tolist())).tolist()
10 loops, best of 3: 99.2 ms per loop

#John Galt's solution
In [64]: %timeit list(set(df.available_fruits.sum()))
1 loop, best of 3: 4.12 s per loop

#pir's solution 0
In [65]: %timeit list(set(concat(df.available_fruits.values.tolist())))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.16 ms per loop

#pir's solution 1
In [66]: %timeit list({k: 1 for x in df.available_fruits.values.tolist() for k in x})
100 loops, best of 3: 4.59 ms per loop

#pir's solution 2
In [67]: %%timeit
    ...: from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
    ...: 
    ...: mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
    ...: mlb.fit(df.available_fruits)
    ...: list(mlb.classes_)
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 4.07 ms per loop

#perigon's solution
In [68]: %timeit list(set([val for lst in df.available_fruits for val in lst]))
100 loops, best of 3: 5.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: I don't dare to answer when I see `dataframe` tag in question, because I know no one can beat jezrael when it comes pandas, I admire you buddy, learning a lot from you, thanks :) +1

Comment: @akashkarothiya Keep trying buddy. You'll get there some day. Oh, +1 btw.

Answer (score 5):

**Option 0**

```
from cytoolz import concat

list(set(concat(df.available_fruits.values.tolist())))
```

**Option 1**

```
list({k: 1 for x in df.available_fruits.values.tolist() for k in x})

['apple', 'banana', 'tomato', 'kiwi']
```

---

**Option 2**
From left field...

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

MultiLabelBinarizer().fit(df.available_fruits).classes_.tolist()

['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi', 'tomato']
```

---

**Timing**
Conclusions:

- Fastest over small data:

  - `pir1` and `jez2`
- Fastest over large data

  - `pir2` and very close `jez2`

---

```
results.div(results.min(1), 0).round(2).pipe(lambda d: d.assign(Best=d.idxmin(1)))

       pir0  pir1  pir2     galt   jez1  jez2  prgn  Best
N                                                        
1      2.36  1.00  4.43    13.93  10.82  1.00  2.86  pir1
3      1.67  1.51  3.94    12.27   7.20  1.00  2.73  jez2
10     1.59  1.09  4.90     9.90   9.24  1.00  3.03  jez2
30     1.20  1.39  2.44     6.78   9.42  1.00  2.67  jez2
100    1.06  1.45  1.66    12.15  20.50  1.00  2.00  jez2
300    1.13  1.76  1.33    28.30  33.41  1.00  2.01  jez2
1000   1.00  1.70  1.11   111.74  32.79  1.18  1.95  pir0
3000   1.00  1.93  1.02   364.07  32.18  1.03  2.02  pir0
10000  1.08  1.87  1.00  1223.63  35.10  1.03  1.97  pir2
```

[image]

*Code*

```
pir0 = lambda df: list(set(concat(df.available_fruits.values.tolist())))
pir1 = lambda df: list({k: 1 for x in df.available_fruits.values.tolist() for k in x})
pir2 = lambda df: MultiLabelBinarizer().fit(df.available_fruits).classes_.tolist()
galt = lambda df: list(set(df.available_fruits.sum()))
jez1 = lambda df: np.unique(np.concatenate(df['available_fruits'].values.tolist())).tolist()
jez2 = lambda df: list(set(chain.from_iterable(df.available_fruits.values.tolist())))
prgn = lambda df: list(set([val for lst in df.available_fruits for val in lst]))

results = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.Index([1, 3, 10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000, 30000], name='N'),
    columns='pir0 pir1 pir2 galt jez1 jez2 prgn'.split(),
    dtype=float
)

for i in results.index:
    d = pd.concat([df] * i, ignore_index=True)
    for j in results.columns:
        stmt = '{}(d)'.format(j)
        setp = 'from __main__ import d, {}'.format(j)
        results.set_value(i, j, timeit(stmt, setp, number=10))

fig, (a1, a2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 10))
results.plot(loglog=True, ax=a1)
results.div(results.min(1), 0).round(2).plot.barh(logx=True, ax=a2)
```

Comment: For brevity it can be `list({k for x in dff.available_fruits for k in x})`?

Comment: @JohnGalt Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Another way, using list concatenation and `set`, `sum` on lists joins them.

```
In [779]: list(set(df.available_fruits.sum()))
Out[779]: ['tomato', 'kiwi', 'apple', 'banana']
```

But, use `chain.from_iterable` method from @jezrael or @perigon's flatten list approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you're OK with a set as output:

```
set([val for lst in df.available_fruits for val in lst])
```

Of course, you can convert this to a list:

```
list(set([val for lst in df.available_fruits for val in lst]))
```

Comment: This is one of the fastest methods.